# Jenkins does not show changes from last build to latest build

Tags: jenkins

I am currently seeing an issue in jenkins that even if there is a change in the build, it always says 'No changes from last build'(which is taken from perforce). And in the console output I see that mail is triggered to concerned people who have modified the file in the latest build.

Any Idea what could be the reason ?

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this issue reported on the Jenkins site: '[Polling builds project regardless of changes](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5915)'?

Perhaps it is related to the issue you are having.